# File.WriteAllLines don't write æ, ø letters

Tags: c#, wpf, file

I have a string array "s" and then `File.WriteAllLines(path, s);` and when i open the file, æ & ø are replaced by �. How can i fix this ?

Comment: You have encoding problems. Start here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: "and when i open the file" - with what are you opening the file?

Comment: Also: do you mean `WriteAllText`? does that even *compile* as posted?

Comment: Notepad but that dont matter.

Comment: Sorry "s" is a string[].

Comment: Have you tried opening your file with an editor that supports properly and can also switch/convert encodings (like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Programmers notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/))?

Comment: "Notepad but that dont matter" - yes, yes it does. This is entirely down to the tool that is doing the reading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `File.WriteAllLines` and `File.WriteAllText` use UTF-8 if no `Encoding` is specified. Specifically, it is UTF-8 without a BOM (which is pretty normal).

So: either read the file with an editor that understands UTF-8, or explicitly specify the alternative `Encoding` that you want to use.

Comment: There's a lot of sadness in that "pretty normal" comment.  I'll never understand why that's considered "normal".

Comment: @user re your deleted answer: don't use Encoding.Default

Comment: Why don't use Encoding.Default ?

Comment: @user2635745 You could use `File.WriteAllLines(path, s, Encoding.UTF8);` as that will use UTF-8 ***with*** byte-order-mark (BOM) and hence should open correctly in "poor" text editors like Notepad.

Comment: @user the answer to that is simple: first, do you know what an Encoding is? if not: go find out - then, second question: what is Encoding.Default ? once you can answer both if those, you'll know exactly why not to use Encoding.Default

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem : `File.WriteAllLines(path, s, Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: Why don't you accept @MarcGravell's answer then? He's answer was entirely correct.

Comment: Well, don't do *that*, it just delays the misery.  Pass Encoding.UTF8 instead.  Notepad can now properly identify the encoding, as can many other programs that process text files anywhere in the world.